# Serial port only recognized with acpi=off boot flag

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, acpi

I have a computer with a skylake motherboard (ASRock IMB-195), and I'm trying to use the on-board serial port (/dev/ttyS0). I'm using Ubuntu Server with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-72.

If I boot with acpi=off, I get the following output (dmesg):

```
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 3, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

with acpi on:

```
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
```

Completely disabling ACPI is very suboptimal (can't reboot without manually power cycling for example).

Is there a way to disable the parts of ACPI that are preventing the serial driver from working?

Comment: First step would be to compare `dmesg` after boot with and without `acpi=off`, and see what goes wrong. There are also tools to decode the ACPI tables (but the ACPI spec is difficult, this isn't fun).

Answer (score 2):

You can try "acpi=noirq" instead. That's the only way I can get my ttyS0 to work with Serial-Over-Lan on an Intel AMT platform. It doesn't seem to have any ill effects but if anyone else knows a better solution, please share.